# How do you allow users to subscribe to a Wordpress blog?

Tags: blog, subscription

How do you allow users to subscribe to a Wordpress blog? I need to create a widget that let users receive an email to a blog post, basically a link and an image like we see when we share links on social media. What's the general way of doing this without using a paid service like mailchimp?

Comment: There are RSS feeds out of the box. If you want emails then you can probably write that yourself, or there are other plugins, but if you want reliable delivery to thousands of people you're probably going to have to use someone like Mailchimp somewhere down the line,

Comment: But I need to let user subscribe to the newsfeed by simply entering their email inside a form. RSS itself doesn't really allow you to do that.

Comment: How do you generate your newsfeed?